# C/C++ compiling different parts of the program with different compilers

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, c++11, g++

I'm writing a program in C++ that requires a call to a subroutine written in an open source C program. The C file is called shd.c. (There is no header file for shd in the program). The C program by itself compiles fine with the gcc compiler, and the C++ program works fine when compiling it with g++ without the reference to the C file.

However, g++ very much does not like the C program, giving hundreds of errors and warnings when I compile shd by itself with g++, and I get the same problems when compiling the the C++ program when I includes the C files.

As of now, the way I'm including the C file looks like this:

```
extern "C"{
#include "shd"
}
```

Anyway, I think that my only option here (correct me if I'm wrong) is to compile the C and C++ files separately, with different compilers. Is there any way to do this? I would also point out that I'm using NetBeans, if that makes any difference.

Comment: A build tool like `make` can invoke different compilers for different languages.

Comment: What kind of error messages do you get when compiling C code with g++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gcc` for `shd.c` and `g++` for c++ files. But there is a name mangling for C++ function names, so you can't directly call (by name) C function from C++ or C++ function from C code. To be able to call them, you should declare the function to be called with `extern "C"`.

There is classic way of doing so: Create `shd.h` C/C++ file with declarations:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
 extern "C" {
#endif

extern int shd_a(int, int);
extern int shd_b(int, int);
...

#ifdef __cplusplus 
 }
#endif
```

and include it both in `shd.c` and in c++ files.